# Eased Scrolling Effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, easing

I'm trying to find out what method this [site](http://www.buildinamsterdam.com/case/trefecta-mobility) uses to achieve their eased scrolling effect.

I searched through their [minified code](http://www.buildinamsterdam.com/app/themes/bia/build/app.min.js) and found some instances of 'scroll', but nothing I can use to identify how it's being done:

```
...Width":"Height",o="scroll"+r,s="client"+r,a=document.body;return n===e||...
```

Any ideas what code, method or library is being used to get this scrolling effect?

Thanks in advance for any help you may have.